# Can't extract elements from a list inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, serial-port

While attempting to create a simple program to read data from a RS232 device, I noticed that I can't access the elements in a list inside a while loop.

This list are the bytes read from the serial port (using pyserial).

```py
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

#To request Distances & Echoes, the following frame has to be sent
packet = bytearray()
packet.append(0xde)
packet.append(0x01)
packet.append(0x05)
packet.append(0x59)
packet.append(0x83)


try:
    while 1:
        ser.write(packet)
        ser_bytes = ser.read(50)

        listDistances = list(ser_bytes)
        distance0_lsb = listDistances[4]  #distance 0 (LSB)
        distance0_msb = listDistances[5]  #distance 0 (MSB)

finally:
    ser.close()
```

listDistances[4] throws an "index out of range" error

Do I need threading to be able to be keep updating the list while extracting elements from it?

Comment: Have you tried accessing `listDistances` outside of the while loop? and what do you get when you print the whole list? (print it both inside and outside the while loop)

Comment: Why would you assume you need threading before inspecting the result of `listDistances = list(ser_bytes)`? Also, I would suggest importing `time` and using `sleep` in your loop rather than hammering the device

Comment: I can print the whole list and all elements are there (int). If I access listDistances[x] outside of the loop, I get no error. But I need the elements to be constantly updated...

Comment: They can't all be there. `IndexError` is not a lie from Python. You need to wrap this in a `try`/`except` and catch the response that throws the index error. On exception, print the value.

Comment: If I try to slice the list I can access it, for example: distance0_lsb = listDistances[4:5]. This successfully creates a new list with one element, but I really need to have the element as an integer to be able to do some calculations with it.

Answer (score 0):

Python list indexes start with 0, which means that in your example `listDistances[5]` would raise "index out of range" if your list has only 5 elements.

If you want `distance0_lsb` and `distance0_msb` to read the last two elements in `listDistances` you could use:

```
distance0_lsb = listDistances[-2]
distance0_msb = listDistances[-1]
```

Negative indexes in python go through the list backwards.

Comment: I understand that, the problem here is not me accessing a non-existent element per se. When I print the list I can see all 50 elements

Comment: "listDistances[4] throws an "index out of range" error". Note that that index is 1 less than the next index that they try to access. So it can't be an off-by-one error because they intent to access higher indices

Comment: I am sorry, I think I misunderstood your problem then. Can you make an example that does not depend on the serial connection so that it would be easier for other people to run it? Maybe using `bytes(50)` instead of `ser.read(50)`. If that works, though, your problem may be in the serial itself. Notice that [ser.read(50)](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read) can return less than 50 bytes in case of timeout, for example.